# Getting an error for initalisation of the constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, namespaces

This is my process.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
  #include "process.h"
  #include "CString.h"
   void process(const char* s){
    w1::Cstring cs(s);
    std::cout << cs;
   }
```

My CString.h

```
#ifndef _CSTRING_H
#define _CSTRING_H
#include<iostream>
namespace w1{
const int CHAR_NUM=3;
class Cstring{
public:
    char str[CHAR_NUM+1];
    Cstring(char* s);
    void display(std::ostream& os) const;

};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os ,const Cstring& cs);
}
#endif
```

And this is my CString.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CString.h"
namespace w1{
Cstring::Cstring(char* s){
    if (s=='\0'){
        str[0]='\0';
    }else{
        for (int i=0;i<CHAR_NUM;i++){
            str[i]=s[i];
            str[i+1]='\0';
        }
    }
}
void Cstring::display(std::ostream& os) const{
    os<<str<<std::endl;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os ,const Cstring& cs){
    cs.display(os);
    return os;
}
}
```

I am getting an error which says that I dont have any matching constructor for initialisation of w1::CString in process.cpp
I dont know how to correct it.

Comment: That constructor should take a `const char*`. (It's also broken in other ways.)

Answer (score 4):

You wrote your constructor `Cstring(char* s);` as taking a non-const pointer. But your function `void process(const char* s)` is trying to pass it a const pointer. The compiler won't automatically cast away constness (and for good reason).

However since that constructor doesn't seem to be modifying its parameter, you should change it to a const pointer:

```
Cstring(const char* s);
```

And thus that error will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing the parameter type of the constructor to `const char *` instead, if the constructor does not modify the parameter, as in your code. Compilers are allowed to implicitly convert non-`const` to `const`, but not the other way around, as your code shows.